# Automatically open README/readme/etc with less?

Tags: linux, shell

<del>I come up with a solution to this problem,write a piece of script call readme who internal call the less with the current directory readme-alike txt file.</del>

Is there any software to do so?<del>I do not want to reinvent the wheel.</del>

thanks.

Comment: The effort sounds so short that it would not matter if you write it from scratch.

Comment: Sorry for that,so you could think I'm just looking for that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to not have to know the filename specifically to open any given, case-insensitive 'readme' files?

Something like this perhaps (but it will fail on filenames with spaces):

```
alias readme='ls -1 | grep -i read | grep -i me | xargs less'
```

From @[~Quack](https://superuser.com/users/12786/quack)'s comment, if you want to handle spaces, too:

```
alias readme='find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*read*me*' -print0 | xargs -0 less'
```

Comment: i think this will work for "README" "readme" and "read_me" but break on "Read Me".  maybe `find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*read*me*' -print0 | xargs -0 less`

Comment: and it may not get newlines properly - depends on how ls formats..

Comment: you're right, if it has a space it doesn't work